# Google Chrome extension GMAIL to generate URL with parameters

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a customer database. Now I would like to create a Chrome extension that allows me to generate an URL with parameters within GMAIL.
The parameters I would like to add are the email address and name of a certain person of which I have the email openend in GMAIL.

So for example email from person John Doe, john@doe.com is open, next to the person click a button that opens an URL : http://customerdatabe.com/insert_person.php?name='John Doe'&email=john@doe.com.

So far I've created a chrome extension.
Now I'm trying to get the from address variable of the open message in GMAIL.

How do I get the content of span.gD email="automail@bol.com"? So not the actual content of the span but the value of email="???".
I'm using document.querySelector("span.gD").textContent
This is the source from Gmail:

```
<span class="gI">
<span email="automail@bol.com" name="bol.com" data-hovercard-id="automail@bol.com" class="gD">bol.com</span> 
<span class="go"><span aria-hidden="true">&lt;</span>automail@bol.com
<span aria-hidden="true">&gt;</span>
</span> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

```
document.querySelector("span.gD").getAttribute("email")
```